# How to line up numbers in columns where last row numbers have percent sign

Tags: excel, formatting

All the columns for numbers are right-aligned. The row with secondary totals should have a percent sign (%), but the digits should still line up. I tried single-character indent for all numbers except this row, but no variation of font produces digits lining up.

I also tried adding a thin column just to house the percent sign on that row, but, alas, there seems to be some built-in column margin or padding so it looks like 26 % instead of 26%. Anybody know a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Custom number format

```
_-* #,##0_%
```

The trailing `_%` means include a space the width of the `%` character

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

If this is what you're after: then change the right indent to be 1 character for the cells before the %

- Select range.
- right click
- select format cells
- select alignment
- change horizontal to "right (indent)"
- Change Indent to 1

Added courier new to show the even better alignment

Comment: Hi. Yes, exactly what i was after. What font is that? ..as it doesn't work that nicely with most fonts. I'm using WinXP Excel 2003 at work.

Comment: courier new will give you the best results; it's a fixed length font. I was using...calibri 11 which isn't quite as nice.  The problem with most fonts is that they are variable in length for each character.  Courier New is the same size for ALL characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go with Courier New..although it might not quite be the same in this version of windows and excel. Microsoft did improve their fonts and rendering after WinXP. I do see slight mis-alignment in the screenshot with Courier New but, that might be the best possible, apart from inserting text boxes and aligning painfully by eye. It's a shame that Excel isn't more geared towards the professional display of data.